# is it right comprehension convert to normal python code?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

below code is use comprehension with for loop

```
n_outputs = len(set([row[-1] for row in train]))
```

And i convert to normally python code for understand why author make this code.

```
for row in train:
    n_outputs = len(set[row - 1])
```

is it right convert to normally for loop code?

Comment: what is train? Is it a list?

Comment: The 2 versions should give different results...

Comment: Another pyrrhic victory for (in)comprehensions :-o

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `train` variable is a list of string,

`n_outputs = len(set([row[-1] for row in train]))`

will find the number of distinct last character in your `train` list

To convert that into a loop,

```
n_outputs = set()
for row in train:
    n_outputs.add(row[-1])
n_outputs = len(n_outputs)
```

will yield the same result

Answer (score 0):

The comprehension is the innermost part of this statement - you need to convert this to a for loop first, literally converted it goes something like this (untested):

```
rowends = []
for row in trains:
    rowends.append(row[-1])
n_outputs = len(set(rowends))
```

Once written like this, you might choose to adapt to build a set for rowends rather than a list. The set is used to eliminate duplicate entries.